# DevExtreme setCellValue not working as intended

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devextreme

I'm using DevExtreme for my project. I have a datagrid rendering with the data I want and now I need to add the ability for users to select individual rows so they can do bulk changes via a drop down menu / selection box.

The issue I'm facing is getting my selected column to update its value based on the drop down menus selected value.

This is what I have so far:

```
function cboApprovedSelectAll_Changed(data) {
    // get datagrid
    var grid = $("#grid-container").dxDataGrid("instance");

// get selected box value
var selectedValue = data.value;

if (selectedValue == null)
    return;

if (confirm('Do you want to set ALL approval status to ' + (selectedValue == "Approved" ? "Approved" : "Declined") + "?")) {
    var indicies = grid.getSelectedRowKeys();

    //this.grid.cellValue(19079, "ApprovalStatus", "rawr");

    for (var counter = 0; counter < indicies.length; counter++) {
        console.log(indicies[counter]); // returns a value
        console.log(selectedValue);     // returns the correctly selected value

        // set selected rows cell value to that of the drop down 
        grid.cellValue(indicies[counter], "ApprovalStatus", selectedValue);
    }
}
grid.saveEditData();
```

}

When I fire this code snippet I can get correctly rows index returned as well as the selected value displaying in the console. Yet the value in the datagrid remains the same with no message forthcoming from the log either.

I've tried using this with hard coded values (which you can see commented out after the second if statement) and adding `this` before it but that generates the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cellValue' of undefined
```

What do I need to change in order to get my datagrid cell to update its value correctly?

And my datagrid with the column below:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
        .ID("grid-container")
                .DataSource(ds => ds
                .WebApi()
                .Controller("sample")
                .UpdateAction("update")
                .LoadAction("load")
                .Key("Id")

                ) // end of datasource
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add().DataField("ApprovalStatus").AllowEditing(false);
                })
                .Paging(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
                .Pager(pager =>
                {
                    pager.ShowPageSizeSelector(true);
                    pager.AllowedPageSizes(new List<int> { 5, 10, 20 });
                    pager.ShowInfo(true);
                })
                .FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
                .HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
                .GroupPanel(p => p.Visible(true))
                .ShowBorders(true)
                .ShowRowLines(true)
                .ColumnAutoWidth(true)
                .SearchPanel(sp => sp.Visible(true))
                .Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Multiple))


) @*end of data grid*@
```

Comment: is `ApprovalStatus` a `dataField`? Meaning, is `ApprovalStatus` an identifier of the **column**? usually, to update grid data, it's enough to call `saveEditData()` after altering data. If the grid is not updating, you're likely providing wrong data to the `cellValue` method. Can you please provide a verifiable example? Sharing the `dxDataGrid` config would be useful, here.

Comment: @briosheje updated my question with the datagrid. I can't/wont supply the loading logic for the datagrid but that parts works.

Comment: What is the type of `ApprovalStatus`? object?